# How can I create a file from My Files?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, files

This seems like a silly question, but how do you create a file in My Files? I've been searching for a while on Google and this site, but I cannot find out how!

When I pres the "menu" key, I can see an option to create a folder, but there's no option to create a file. So, how can I create a file, for example, "filename.html", from the My Files viewer?

I am using a Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `My Files` does not allow you to create files. You could try a 3rd-party app like [File Expert](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&hl=en) though; this app lets you create both files and folders.